# Format phone number in UITextField using libPhoneNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, libphonenumber

How to format any phone number with **International Phone Number format** in `UITextField` on each character input for any country using **libPhoneNumber-iOS**?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to use the [libPhoneNumber-iOS](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS)? You should just read their README page which has a rich set of examples.

One basic sample is as follow:

```
NBPhoneNumberUtil *phoneUtil = [[NBPhoneNumberUtil alloc] init];
NSError *anError = nil;
NBPhoneNumber *myNumber = [phoneUtil parse:@"6766077303"
                          defaultRegion:@"AT" error:&anError];
if (anError == nil) {
    [phoneUtil format:myNumber 
         numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatINTERNATIONAL
                error:&anError];
}
```

Comment: I have seen it previously. It is providing mobile format for valid number. I need to format on each number input in textfield.

Comment: I have also seen Class NBAsYouTypeFormatter to format but it provides input digit only at the end of string. But my requirement is that user can input digit in between the string of textfield at any place. Ex. If textfield has 9176543 then user can input at any index and also maintain formatting.

Comment: @ItsMeMihir Yes. Base on the comment [here](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS/blob/496d5230dccc77f368a8bf96d6bacb62e069864e/libPhoneNumber/NBAsYouTypeFormatter.m#L276) it is using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1